# Javascript: Show message on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I want to show some message in `span` tag after my `form` gets submitted to the server. The problem is, the text disappears within seconds. Is it because the page is `reloaded`? Can anyone spot what is wrong with my function?

```
function placeOrder(form) {
    if (validateLength(1, 32, form["bannerMessage"], form["messageError"]) &&
     validateZipField(form["zipField"], form["zipError"]) &&
        validateEmptyFields(form["dateField"], form["dateError"]) &&
        validateEmptyFields(form["nameField"], form["nameError"]) &&
        validateEmptyFields(form["phoneField"], form["phoneError"]) &&
        validateEmptyFields(form["emailField"], form["emailError"])) {
        // Submit the order to the server
        form.submit();
       document.getElementById("submitSuccess").innerHTML = "Submitted successfully";


    } else {
        alert("I'm sorry but there is something wrong with the order information.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, you are sending the form to the server who will send back a complete page.

What you should do is have the new page contain the message that the form was successfully sent, or if there was a problem with the form (you do server-side validation, right?) -- give the details of the error.

For usability, it is important to make sure that you keep all of the form-fields you can. (E-Commerce fields are special, but keep everything else.)